# Set Rails value over multiple lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiline

In Rails, you can create an anchor tag that spans multiple lines doing something like the following:

```
<% link_to target_url_path do %>
    <span class="title">Example</span>
    <span class="excerpt">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum...</span>
    <%= image_tag 'example.png', :class => 'thumbnail' %>
<% end >
```

I'm wondering how I can set a value using a similar approach.  In essence, something like:

```
<% my_variable = do %>
    <span class="title">Example</span>
    <span class="excerpt">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum...</span>
    <%= image_tag 'example.png', :class => 'thumbnail' %>
<% end >
```

Edit: in case anyone is curious why I'm asking, it's because `facebox_link_to` doesn't appear to allow you to use the `do` syntax like `link_to` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know what you want to do, however you can use the `#tap` pattern.

```
<% my_variable.tap do |variable| %>
  <span class="title">Example</span>
  <span class="excerpt">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum...</span>
  <%= image_tag 'example.png', :class => 'thumbnail' %>
<% end %>
```

If instead you want to assign a chunk of code to a variable, then you are doing it wrong because views shouldn't set variables in that way.

Instead, use an helper.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `tap` pattern? I'm interested in reading more about this. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: `syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND`

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Object.html#M000191 Also read http://bit.ly/aYgkKe for Rails 3.0

Comment: Also counter to the MVC pattern, or am I missing something? Thanks for the `tap` link. +1

Comment: @Matt On which line? Which Ruby version?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Comment: Okay, so I had to define `my_variable` first with any garbage data to make sure it's declared.  It worked after that.

Comment: It was backported to 1.8.7 (which is the minimum version for Rails 3).

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively rendering an inline template. You can use `render :inline` for this:

```
<% my_variable = render :inline => <<-EOS
<span class="title">Example</span>
<span class="excerpt">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum...</span>
#{image_tag 'example.png', :class => 'thumbnail'}
EOS
%>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please, don't do that. You are killing the MVC pattern!

Comment: A helper, as you suggested, is the way forward. This is my literalist answer to the question.